# Creating Lilliefors test in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Can someone help me create Lilliefors test in Matlab so that I could compare values with the given function: [h,p,kstat,critval] = lillietest( ). I do not know how to compare data after standardization, as given vectors have different length. This is the beginning of my code:

```
clear;
clc;

[prices_daily] =xlsread(...);

logreturns_daily = log(prices_daily(2:end,:))-log(prices_daily(1:end-1,:)); % daily log returns

m = mean(logreturns_daily);
s = std(logreturns_daily);
z=(prices_daily(1:end,1)-m)/s;

e = ecdf(z);
n = normcdf(z);
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to normalize, since [Lillietest](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/lillietest.html) tests for Normality whichever the mean and standard deviation are. Simply apply:

```
  [h,p,k,c]=lillietest(prices_daily(1:end,1),'Alpha',0.01);
```

Comment: The problem is that I have to program the functionality of Lillietest and do not use the built in function

Comment: So, for a given data vector $x$, you need to compare if both functions say the sample comes from a Normal Distribution?

Comment: Exactly I have to manually program the steps of Lilliefors test